# Falha ao inserir dados no banco pelo RadioGroup

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, delphi-7

Estou tentando salvar uma informação no banco através de um RadioGroup, porém ao invés de salvar na coluna `Status` que possuo no banco a palavra **ativo** ele tenta encontrar a coluna **ativo**. meu formulário está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E meu `Insert` está assim:

```
begin
    sdsEmpresaCadastro.Close;
    sdsEmpresaCadastro.CommandText := 'select * from Empresa where Nome = '''+cdsEmpresaNOME.AsString + '''';
    sdsEmpresaCadastro.Open;

    if not sdsEmpresaCadastro.IsEmpty then
       raise  Exception.Create('Empresa já incluída');
    cdsEmpresaCODIGO.AsInteger := dmDatabase.NextID('EMPRESA');
    dmDatabase.SQLConnection.Execute('INSERT INTO Empresa (CODIGO, NOME, VALORIMPRESSAO, '+
         'VALORDIGITALIZACAO, VALORIMPRESSAOEXCEDENTE, CONTATO, NOMEREDUZIDO, CNPJ, ENDERECO, BAIRRO, CEP, '+
         'CIDADE, TEFONE, UF, INSCRICAOESTADUAL, CONTATONF, EMAIL, EMAILNF, OBSERVACAO, '+
         'FRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO, STATUS, VALORDIGITALIZACAOEXCEDENTE) VALUES ('+
         cdsEmpresaCODIGO.AsString+','''+cdsEmpresaNOME.AsString+''','+
         TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORIMPRESSAO.AsString)+','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAO.AsString='','0', TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAO.AsString))+','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaVALORIMPRESSAOEXCEDENTE.AsString='','0', TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORIMPRESSAOEXCEDENTE.AsString))+
         ','''+cdsEmpresaCONTATO.AsString+''','''+cdsEmpresaNOMEREDUZIDO.AsString+ ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaCNPJ.AsString +''','''+cdsEmpresaENDERECO.AsString+''','''+
         cdsEmpresaBAIRRO.AsString +''','''+cdsEmpresaCEP.AsString+ ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaCIDADE.AsString+''','''+cdsEmpresaTEFONE.AsString+''','''+
         cdsEmpresaUF.AsString+''','''+cdsEmpresaINSCRICAOESTADUAL.AsString+ ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaCONTATONF.AsString+ ''','''+ cdsEmpresaEMAIL.AsString + ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaOBSERVACAO.AsString + ''','''+ cdsEmpresaEMAILNF.AsString+''','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaFRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO.AsString='','0', cdsEmpresaFRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO.AsString)+','+
         cdsEmpresastatus.AsString +','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAOEXCEDENTE.AsString='','0', TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAOEXCEDENTE.AsString))+')', nil);
  end
```

Já tentei apenas salvar direto a palavra **ativo** no banco, porém nem assim está salvando, mesmo assim ele acusa esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tiverem alguma ideia de o que poderia alterar, ou o que poderia estar causando tal erro, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta você adicionar as aspas simples.

Tente usar a função [`QuotedStr`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_QuotedStr.html) para adicionar as aspas simples, ficando da seguinte forma

```
QuotedStr(cdsEmpresastatus.AsString)
```