# Erro ao salvar dados de um RadioGroup

Tags: delphi, postgresql, delphi-7

Estou com um problema para salvar as informações que seleciono em um `RadioGroup` no Banco de dados, após fazer a alteração que foi sugerida nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176716/falha-ao-inserir-dados-no-banco-pelo-radiogroup/176724#176724) o erro de tentar adicionar algo na coluna **Ativo** parou, porém em alguns casos está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo o `Insert` da seguinte forma:

```
begin
    sdsSuprimentoCadastro.Close;
    sdsSuprimentoCadastro.ParamByName('SUPRIMENTO').AsString := cdsSuprimentoSuprimento.AsString;
    sdsSuprimentoCadastro.Open;
    if not sdsSuprimentoCadastro.IsEmpty then
       raise  Exception.Create('Cadastro para Suprimento já incluído');
    cdsSuprimentoCodigo.AsInteger := dmDatabase.NextID('SUPRIMENTO');
      dmDatabase.SQLConnection.Execute('INSERT INTO SUPRIMENTO (CODIGO, SUPRIMENTO, CAPACIDADE, '+
       'CODIGOTIPOSUPRIMENTO, ESTOQUEMINIMO, QUANTIDADEML, PARTNUMBER, STATUS, DESCRICAO) VALUES ('+ cdsSuprimentoCodigo.AsString+','''+
       cdsSuprimentoSuprimento.AsString+''','+
       cdsSuprimentoCapacidade.AsString + ',' + cdsSuprimentoCODIGOTIPOSUPRIMENTO.AsString + ',' +
       cdsSuprimentoEstoqueMinimo.AsString +','''+cdsSuprimentoQuantidadeML.AsString +
       ''','''+cdsSuprimentoPartNumber.AsString+ ''','''+QuotedStr(cdsSuprimentostatus.AsString)+ ''','''+cdsSuprimentoDESCRICAO.AsString+''')', nil);
  end
```

Meu `update` esta assim:

```
else
    dmDatabase.SQLConnection.Execute('UPDATE Suprimento SET SUPRIMENTO = '''+cdsSuprimentoSuprimento.AsString+
        ''', CAPACIDADE = '''+ cdsSuprimentoCapacidade.AsString +
        ''', CODIGOTIPOSUPRIMENTO = '+ cdsSuprimentoCODIGOTIPOSUPRIMENTO.AsString +
        ', QUANTIDADEML = '''+ cdsSuprimentoQuantidadeML.AsString +
        ''', PARTNUMBER = '''+ cdsSuprimentoPartNumber.AsString +
        ''', DESCRICAO = '''+ cdsSuprimentoDESCRICAO.AsString +
        ''', STATUS = '''+ QuotedStr(cdsSuprimentostatus.AsString)+
        ''', ESTOQUEMINIMO = '+ cdsSuprimentoEstoqueMinimo.AsString +
        ' WHERE CODIGO = '+cdsSuprimentoCodigo.AsString, nil);
  frmCadSuprimento.iCodigo := cdsSuprimentoCodigo.AsInteger;
  cdsSuprimento.Close;
  sdsSuprimento.CommandText := 'select * from Suprimento where codigo = 0';
  cdsSuprimento.Open;
```

a tabela esta configurada assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Se tiverem alguma ideia de o que pode estar causando tal erro, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vejo que você tem uma coluna `DESCRICAO` logo a cima do status, ela também precisa do `QuotedStr`

Ficando assim

```
var update: string;
begin
  update =
        ' UPDATE Suprimento ' +
        ' SET SUPRIMENTO = ' + QuotedStr(cdsSuprimentoSuprimento.AsString) +
        '   , CAPACIDADE = '+ cdsSuprimentoCapacidade.AsString +
        '   , CODIGOTIPOSUPRIMENTO = '+ cdsSuprimentoCODIGOTIPOSUPRIMENTO.AsString +
        '   , QUANTIDADEML = '+ QuotedStr(cdsSuprimentoQuantidadeML.AsString) +
        '   , PARTNUMBER = '+ QuotedStr(cdsSuprimentoPartNumber.AsString) +
        '   , DESCRICAO = '+ QuotedStr(cdsSuprimentoDESCRICAO.AsString) +
        '   , STATUS = '+ QuotedStr(cdsSuprimentostatus.AsString)+
        '   , ESTOQUEMINIMO = '+ cdsSuprimentoEstoqueMinimo.AsString +
        ' WHERE CODIGO = '+cdsSuprimentoCodigo.AsString;

  dmDatabase.SQLConnection.Execute(update, nil);
end;
```

Sempre que tiver um campo que seja `Varchar` procure usar o `QuotedStr`.

Comment: fiz essa edição no meu Update e o erro passou a ser na descrição agora, mostra a mesma janela de erro só que agora ele me mostra o que esta no campo descrição `Syntax error at or near "**o que esta no campo descricao**"`

Comment: Compartilha a instrução create de sua tabela por favor.

Comment: Eu tenho ela no PostGreSQL apenas, poderia ser a imagem de como a tabela esta configurada? Com as colunas, etc.

Comment: Colunas e tipo de dados

Comment: Editei a pergunta com a imagem de como esta configurado o BAnco

Comment: Resposta editada

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Pablo Vargas